# How To Change The URL Of A Link In A WebGrid Depending On Clients Age

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

I have a `List<WebGridColumn>`table that displays a list of clients, both adult and child.  Depending on the clients age they have a different URL so adults are
/secure/client/[Page URL] and a child's is /secure/junior/[Page URL].

The issue I have is that I cant figure out how to make my link the user clicks direct them to the correct URL.

Below is what I have that doesn't work:

```
List<WebGridColumn> cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
        cols.Add(new WebGridColumn { Header = "Client name", ColumnName = "ClientName", CanSort = true, Format = (item) => String.Format("<a onclick=\"showPopUp()\" href=\"/Secure/Adviser/Client/?ClientIdentifier={0}\">{1}</a>", item.Identifier, item.ClientName) });
        cols.Add(new WebGridColumn { Header = "Account number", ColumnName = "AccountNumber", CanSort = true });
        foreach (ClientViewColumn c in currentClientView.Columns)
        {
```

This works fine for adults due to the `href` set

I have tried adding an `if`statement around it but this causes a server error as show below:

```
List<WebGridColumn> cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
        if (AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.UserDetails.IsJunior())
        {
            cols.Add(new WebGridColumn { Header = "Client name", ColumnName = "ClientName", CanSort = true, Format = (item) => String.Format("<a onclick=\"showPopUp()\" href=\"/Secure/Adviser/Junior/?ClientIdentifier={0}\">{1}</a>", item.Identifier, item.ClientName) });
        }
        else
        {
            cols.Add(new WebGridColumn { Header = "Client name", ColumnName = "ClientName", CanSort = true, Format = (item) => String.Format("<a onclick=\"showPopUp()\" href=\"/Secure/Adviser/Client/?ClientIdentifier={0}\">{1}</a>", item.Identifier, item.ClientName) });
        }   
        cols.Add(new WebGridColumn { Header = "Account number", ColumnName = "AccountNumber", CanSort = true });
        foreach (ClientViewColumn c in currentClientView.Columns)
        {
```

How do I do it as I cant think of a way to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable in your view as follows:

```
var isJunior = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.UserDetails.IsJunior();
```

Then evaluate it as follows in your `string.Format`:

```
 (isJunior ? "Junior" : "Client")
```

Your code would then become this:

```
    var isJunior = AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.UserDetails.IsJunior();
    List<WebGridColumn> cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
        cols.Add(new WebGridColumn { Header = "Client name", 
        ColumnName = "ClientName", CanSort = true, 
        Format = (item) => 
        String.Format("<a onclick=\"showPopUp()\" href=\"/Secure/Adviser/{2}/?ClientIdentifier={0}\">{1}</a>", item.Identifier, item.ClientName, (isJunior ? "Junior" : "Client")) });
...
```